# Deploy list views of classes, pages, etc

Tags: metadata-api, migration

Salesforce now allows users to define List Views for Classes, Pages, etc.  But I can't figure out how to deploy these to other orgs!  Typically, list views are deployed as part of the CustomObject metadata type, but classes and pages aren't Objects.  Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe you can do this.

Apex Classes and Pages are two files in the metadata, the .cls or .page file for source code and a *-meta.xml file containing the API version number and status.

There is no container into which such a list view definition could be put (unlike a CustomObject).

Answer (score 1):

List Views can be deployed separately. Please check out the [metadata documentation](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_meta/Content/meta_listview.htm).

Sample XML looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CustomObject xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
. . .
    <listViews>
        <fullName>All_Mileages</fullName>
        <filterScope>all</filterScope>
        <label>All Mileages</label>
    </listViews>
    <listViews>
        <fullName>My_Mileages</fullName>
        <booleanFilter>1 AND 2</booleanFilter>
        <columns>NAME</columns>
        <columns>CREATED_DATE</columns>
        <filterScope>mine</filterScope>
        <filters>
            <field>NAME</field>
            <operation>equals</operation>
            <value>Eric Bristow</value>
        </filters>
        <filters>
            <field>City__c</field>
            <operation>equals</operation>
            <value>Paris</value>
        </filters>
        <label>My Mileages</label>
    </listViews>
. . .
</CustomObject>
```

Comment: And this also applies to Pages and Classes, which aren't CustomObjects?

Comment: I have not tested it myself, but I would assume so as long as you provide the proper fullName which should go to a specific API name.

Comment: @Benj my understanding is this only works for custom objects and I believe custom settings, most of the setup area config remains largely absent from the metadata api